# How to hide react component on route changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react router dom's location prop to setState to false and render component only If it's true like this in react :

```
const [ showFilter, setShowFilter ] = useState(false);
const location = useHistory().location;

useEffect(() => {
            switch (location.pathname) {
                case '/signup':
                    return setShowFilter(false);
                case '/add/:id':
                    console.log(location);
                    return setShowFilter(false);
                default:
                    return setShowFilter(true);
            }
        },
        [ location ]
    );

   <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
   <Route exact path="/add/:id" component={AddPage} />
```

```
{showFilter ? <FilterComp class="mr-2" location={location} /> : null}
```

So whenever the location changes the useEffect will run and If location is equal to one of switch cases it will setState to false and FilterComp component will be hidden .

The problem is the `/add/:id` route location pathname will be something like this :

```
/add/2
```

and using '/add/:id' in switch statement doesn't work so I have to know all the :id's and include all of them in switch statement which is impossible .

I cant find a way to include this logic in the switch statement like other routes .

How can I properly setState to false when the location prop has parameters like this `/add/:something` ?

Comment: You may have to use an if statement with a regular expression.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That doesn't solve the issue

Comment: It might do. `:id` acts like a regex, so why not do the same?

Comment: You alway know that route start with `add` so you can do something like this: `location.pathname.includes('/add')`. It will ensure that this path is related to `/add/:something`

Comment: To me it looks like you want a route that matches only if no other routes match. You can achieve that by just adding a ``<Route component={} />`` with not ``path`` attribute at the end. Otherwise, I think suggestions like the one of @evolutionxbox will be the best way to go.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Thanks for helping is there a way to do that in this particular switch statement ?

Comment: No, as swtich statements strictly compare the case values to the expression. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `switch`, you can use `if`.

```
if (location.pathname.startsWith('/add/')) {
    setShowFilter(false)
} else if (location.pathname.startsWith('/signup')) {
    setShowFilter(false)
} else {
    setShowFilter(true)
}
```

Comment: The else's can be omitted as the OP is using early returns.

Comment: Correct. I just took part of the code to demo `switch` vs `if`, without the 'return' :)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you cannot use a regular expression as case of a `switch` statement; you can either use a series of `if...else if...else` statements or do something like this:

```
// ...    
const re = /^(\/signup)|^(\/add\/\d+)/; // a regular expression containing the routes where you want to hide the filter

useEffect(() => {
    setShowFilter(!re.test(location.pathname));
}, [location, re]);
// ...
```